# Sorting with Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting

I am trying to sort a number of integers using 4 threads, splitting the array and then recombining. I think I have accomplished using 2 threads, can anyone help from here how i'd move up to using 4?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class threadSort implements Runnable {
private static final int L = 64;
private static int[] nums;
private static Random rand;

public void run() {
    //sorting upper half
    Arrays.sort(nums, nums.length/2, nums.length);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    nums = new int[L];
    rand = new Random();

    //fill the array
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(new threadSort());
    t.start();

    //sorting lower half
    Arrays.sort(nums, 0, nums.length/2);

    t.join();

    /* merge */
    int j = 0;
    int k = nums.length/2; 
    int[] tmp = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++){
        if (j < nums.length/2) {
            if (k < nums.length) {
                if (nums[j] < nums[k]) {
                    tmp[i] = nums[j++];
                } else {
                    tmp[i] = nums[k++];
                }
            } else {
                /* reached end of second half, copy first*/
                tmp[i] = nums[j++];
            }
        } else {
            /* reached end of 1st half, copy 2nd*/
            tmp[i] = nums[k++];
        }
    }
    nums = tmp;


    //Testing Sort and Total
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
    count++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total amount of Integers = " + count);
}

}
```

thats what i have so far
I want to stick with what i have but throw 2 more threads in

Comment: I would recommend a recursive approach to allow for arrays of indefinite size.

Comment: well i really just wanted it for an array 64 ints.

Comment: I hope this is for homework or personal education. Sorting 64 elements is typically (depending on Comparator implementation) such a trivial operation that the overhead in creating Threads and synchronizing the memory model should far outweigh any performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use [forkjoin](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166ydocs/). Basically you recursively divide your data into binary chunks until you have a small enough chunk you want to work with. Using DL's forkjoin framework is a fun exercise, but if you want to keep it simple, read on.

All you need to do is call your current algorithm twice. That is, use it to break your data in half. Then call your algorithm on each half. When both of those are done, merge their results.

Comment: +1, but... Does Doug Lea go by DL now? General FYI, `ForkJoin` is a part of Java 7's concurrency package (from what I've seen).

Comment: DL was my professor at college. And yes, it is targeted to be in Java 7. See: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2010-September/007435.html